# WPF. Реализация одновременного изменения высоты и ширины окна.

Tags: c#, wpf, gui

Как лучше реализовать такую вещь. Есть окно, и когда я начинаю менять либо высоту либо ширину, то другой параметр менялся соответственно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Биндинг установи (примеров очень много), при этом значения ширины будут зависеть от значений длины (или наоборот).
Есть ещё очень хорошая книга мэтью макдональд - WPF очень много интересного
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873007/wpf-control-width-binding
```